# Permission matching query does not exist in custom permission

Tags: python, django, django-models, permissions, django-views

```
try:
        user = User.objects.get(username = 'xyz')
        custom_permission = Permission.objects.get(codename='is_custom')
        user.user_permissions.add(custom_permission)
        user.save()
        print user.has_perm("is_custom")
        print user.has_perm('app.is_custom')
        user.get_all_permissions()

    except Exception as e:
        print(">>>>>",e)
```

I have done this simple thing to check the user custom permission but it rises the exception

***DoesNotExist('Permission matching query does not exist.')***

what's wrong in this ??

Comment: Might be a silly question but have you made sure the permission has been created?

Comment: yes it's created I've double checked it

Comment: Just making sure =) I have made mistakes like that before. Have you tried the query in the django shell?

Comment: Also, can you your django version to the question please?

Comment: I'm using  Django 1.11 and permission is created I've also checked from  admin panel

Comment: Give it a try in the shell and see what it tells you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get` should return the above error if no Model object satisfies the given condition. ie, there is no Permission object with the codename `is_custom`. You have to modify your query like,

```
custom_permission = Permission.objects.filter(codename='is_custom').first() # return Permission object if exists else None
if custom_permission:
    user.user_permissions.add(custom_permission)
    user.save()
```

Comment: now it shows this  `TypeError("int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'instancemethod'",)`  if i print the custom_permission i get `bound method QuerySet.first of <QuerySet []`

Comment: post the full traceback in your question. I'm sure you passing a method to `int` function.

Comment: I have added `()` after `first`. So there is no such permission.

Comment: this is my latest code ` try:
            user = User.objects.get(username = 'xyz')
            custom_permission = Permission.objects.filter(codename='DELETE').first() # return Permission object if exists else None
            if custom_permission:
                print "in if"
                user.user_permissions.add(custom_permission)
                user.save()
            print "out if"
            print user.has_perm("DELETE")
            print user.has_perm('app.DELETE')
            user.get_all_permissions()

        except Exception as e:
            print(">>>>>",e)   `

Comment: in if
out if
False
False
**and this is out put**

Comment: _user.has_perm('app.DELETE')_ **this must be true not false**

Comment: check if the codename exists `[i.codename for i in Permission.objects.all()]`

Comment: `Permission.objects.filter(codename='DELETE').first()`

Comment: auth | user | can_Delete this is printed but still with **has_perm** it's FALSE

Answer (score -1):

I've created this for permission

`from django.db import models
class RightsSupport(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        permissions = (('DELETE', 'can delete'),)`

in the saparerte file and migrate. this created the something like this in database

**Appname | YourClassContaingPermission | name of permission**

so in my case

app | rights | DELETE

so now if i check like this

**request.user.has_perm('app.DELETE')**

this returns **true**